# My Laravel Vue App Does Not Delete a Record. Do I need to Bind my Button so that it will redirect to the controller?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Hi I am currently making an app with a simple CRUD operation and I am bothered why my code isn't deleting a record whenever I press the delete button. I am a newbie in Laravel and Vue and currently familiarizing the functions and workflows of the 2 frameworks. I have a table called `posts` and it contains `id, title and body`. The app will add a new post and also edits the post and deletes a record. But what actually happened is that the app does not delete a record and I am not sure if a button must bind in order to pass the `id` to the controller. Can you help me please?

Here is my vue page (IndexComponent.vue):

```
<template>
 <div>
  <h1>Posts</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10"></div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'create' }" class="btn btn-primary">Create Post</router-link>
      </div>
    </div><br />
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Item Price</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
                    <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ post.body }}</td>
                    <td><router-link :to="{name: 'edit', params: { id: post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</router-link></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            posts: []
        }
    },
    created(){
        let uri = "/api/posts";
        axios.get(uri).then(response => {
            this.posts = response.data.data;
        });
    },
    methods: {
        deletePost(id) {
            let uri = `/api/post/delete/${id}`;
            axios.delete(uri).then(response => {
            this.posts.splice(this.posts.indexOf(id), 1);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is what's inside my PostController.php :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\PostCollection;
use App\Post;

public function delete($id) {
    $post=Post::find($id);
    $post->delete();
    return response()->json('Successfully deleted!');
}
```

This will be my Route:

```
Route::delete('/post/delete/{id}', 'PostController@delete');
```

Inside my Post.php (Model):

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];
}
```

Everything is actually working except the delete operation and I am still bothered until now. I haven't worked any solution to this problem.

AND BY THE WAY: For the UI. i am using bootstrap 4.3.1 and bootstrap-vue 2.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <tr v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
                <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.body }}</td>
                <td><router-link :to="{name: 'edit', params: { id: post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</router-link></td>
                <td><button @click="deletePost(post.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
```

The reason why it is not deleting because you're not trigging the deletePost function. You should call it on the click event like the code above.